# Whose grave did the doctor and the sheriff visit?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-2007

In [*Halloween* (2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373883/), the doctor and the sheriff visited a grave, which was destroyed by Michael Myers by crucifying a dog to it.

> Sheriff: Who would do sick shit like this?
>
> Doctor: I think I know whose grave that is.

Whose grave was that?

Comment: "As they walk, Chesterfield discovers that the headstone for the Myers plot has been stolen. In its place are the crucified remains of an animal." http://halloweenmovie.wikia.com/wiki/Halloween_(2007_Reboot)

Answer (score 1):

If you remember, when Laurie woke up in the basement of the house they grew up in, there was a headstone next to her.  The headstone was for the Myers' plot, so both his sister Judith and his mother were buried under it.  The [Halloween wiki](https://halloweenmovie.fandom.com/wiki/Michael_Myers/2007_Remake_Timeline) states it was Judith's, but with no first name on it that's not likely.

[image: Myers Headstone]